# SQL HA Secondary replica not synchronizing

Tags: sql-server

I am in process of setting up a HA setup in SQL 2014 (Full recovery model). I found this morning that the secondary replica is in "Not Synchronizing/Suspect" state because of the disk running out of space. I see that the log file has grown way too high.

I see that the log file on primary has also grown way too high.

I am thinking that I'll take a backup of primary and restore that to the secondary replica.

I have taken a full backup of primary. Is there a way to truncate the transaction log at primary without taking a full transaction log backup?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Another place to ask if you need to: http://dba.stackexchange.com/